# Relinquish ownership of auto_ptr contained object

Tags: c++, stl, auto-ptr

I have a class that constructs an `auto_ptr<T>` and gets the `T` object data filled by a utility function. However, I want the `T` object stored by an object manager that will persist the whole life of the application.

The question is - once I have extracted the object that the `auto_ptr` contains, how do I stop the `auto_ptr` from destroying the contained object when it goes out of scope?

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated and should no longer be used.  use `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for my oversight. From the `auto_ptr` documentation;

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/release/

```
std::auto_ptr::release
```

### Release pointer

Sets the `auto_ptr` internal pointer to null pointer (which indicates it points to no object) without destructing the object currently pointed by the `auto_ptr`.

Comment: **[That is _not_ "the `auto_ptr` documentation"](http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/)**.

Comment: Try [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/release) to a website that doesn't suck instead.  Oh, and remember that `auto_ptr` is depreciated, and you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead, unless you have absolutely no choice.

Comment: Thanks LRiO. I didn't realise CPP.com was that bad. Anyway, I didn't mean _the_ documentation, I really meant somewhere that auto_ptr is documented. As for the depreciation, I am aware of that but there is a lot of legacy code I work on that still makes use of it. Will be tackled in future...

Comment: As a further note, CPP.com gives the actual information I need - "Sets the `auto_ptr` internal pointer to null pointer (which indicates it points to no object) without destructing the object currently pointed by the `auto_ptr`", but cppreference.com only states "Releases the held pointer. After the call *this holds the null pointer." with no indication that the object is distroyed or not :/